# WD Black² Dual Drive motor always stops and starts

Tags: hard-drive, software-installation, drive

I installed Ubuntu on a Western Digital WD Black² Dual Drive. Both partitions are working.

But there is still an open problem: 
The motor of the HDD part of the SSHD always stops and starts, over and over. That's not good for the drive.
How can I eliminate this? (I tried laptop-mode-tools and hdparm, but didn't have success)

Comment: it would be great to hear more about how you got the HD portion of the dual drive working in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please look at the comment below. Activation of SSD part was possible only in a Windows-PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the firmware update v5865?

http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=2301&sid=222&lang=en

Comment: @emikesch Can you describe the experience you had with the drive on Ubuntu? Is it working?

Comment: @Adam: It works fine. I use the SSD part for the root "/" and the HDD part for /home. But the activation of the SSD part was only possible in a Windows-PC. So I installed the drive temporarily in a Windows-PC. Be aware of the hardware requirements!

Comment: I agree. I just bought one, activated in under Windows7, and it runs just fine on Ubuntu with bcache. The performance is great, much faster then hybrid SSHD Seagate Momentum.