# Ubuntu and internal WD Digital Black2 Dual Drive -- Did anyone managed to make it work?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

The Western Digital Black2 Dual Drive is a 2.5 drive which combines a 120GB SSD with a 1TB HDD.
It differs from hybrid drives in that it appears to the system as two distinct partitions, leaving to the user to decide what should go on the SSD.
Given my ageing laptop has only one sata interface and no usb 3.0 to attach a fast external drive, I was considering getting this drive.
I need the space and don't want to spend double for a 1tb SDD.

I know that initially the drive was only usable with windows, because there is WD software to be installed in order for the OS to see the two partitions, rather than only the 128gb SSD one.

Did anybody manage to have the WD Black2 work on Ubuntu?
If that's relevant, while Ubuntu will stay my everyday OS, if I upgrade the HD I will be installing Win7 too, to run Lightroom and  some work apps in their native environment.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WD Black² Dual Drive motor always stops and starts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/414356/wd-black%c2%b2-dual-drive-motor-always-stops-and-starts)

Comment: The drive seems to work - see the http://askubuntu.com/questions/414356/wd-black%C2%B2-dual-drive-motor-always-stops-and-starts .

Answer (score 0):

Another poster on  [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414356/wd-black%C2%B2-dual-drive-motor-always-stops-and-starts) seems to have it running. I to am in the same boat as you and could love a confirmation before buying it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
The poster doesn't specify whether he had to do anything specific to have the drive work on Ubuntu.
If it was truly plug and play, aside of having to install the latest firmware, it would be great, but without knowing that for sure it is an expensive experiment. 
Also it would be good to know what is needed for ubuntu to recognize the drive, to future proof purchase in case one wanted at some point to switch to a different distro.